# PHP Markdown \n Question

Tags: regex, markdown

I'm using http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/ for my markdown library and my question is that if i edit and remove the `\n\n` functionality would this work

Because the users that i have, are quite probably not allowed to run JavaScript therefore i cant count on the preview to be generated dynamically therefore they will make allot of mistakes using `\n` instead of `\n\n`

So the question is: is it essential for the library to use the `\n\n` for the reg ex manipulation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research and looking at the markdown convertion, ive noticed that it can be done in such way:

Say for example we have text:

```
asdf
asdf
asdf

asdf
asdf
asdf
```

The output of this in Pure text Markup will be:

```
<p>asdf
asdf
asdf</p>

<p>
asdf
asdf
asdf</p>
```

So to replace the `\n` must only be done inside the `<p>` tags