# regex to match p tags and add br's inside of them

Tags: php, html, regex

Well the question title explains the question :D but here is an example none the less

```
asdf
asdf
<p>asdf
asdf
asdf</p>
```

how to i get it to regex the inside of the p tags and apply nl2br to it so the output would be:

```
asdf
asdf
<p>asdf<br />
asdf<br />
asdf</p>
```

Edit: In PHP

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001311.html

Comment: How regular is the HTML you will be parsing? Do you also need to parse <br> and a <p> block without a closing </p>?

Comment: Im using markdown library, please see this related question to understand more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854862/php-markdown-n-question

Comment: No i dont Doug, Cause i think Markdown will always give me <p></p> and never the situation <p><p></p></p>

Comment: Parsing HTML with a regex? <runs away screaming> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) rather than regex

```
$html = str_get_html(...);

foreach($html->find('p') as $element){
    //get html in p
    $ihtml = p->innertext;

    //apply function
    $ihtml = nl2br($ihtml);

    //save
    $p->innertext = $ihtml;
}

//print the new output
echo $html;
```